# How can I clone and change all ID's of a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone a `table` and change all its ID's adding a prefix.

In the snippet below I change all `tr` elements ID's adding the prefix `my_`, using `.find('tr').each(function()`.

With jQuery, how can I add a prefix name to all ID's of a table during the clone?

```js
var $newTable = $('table.copyable:first').clone();
$newTable.removeClass('copyable');
$newTable
  .find('tr')
  .each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'my_'+$(this).attr('id'));
  });

$('#list-player-songs').html('');
$newTable.appendTo($('#list-player-songs'));
```

```css
table.copyable {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
table td {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Original table</h3>
<table class="copyable">
  <tbody class="sortable">
    <tr id="track251">       
      <td><div data-track-name="love.mp3" id="play251"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url251">love</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track241">       
      <td><div data-track-name="hate.mp3" id="play241"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url241">hate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track233">       
      <td><div data-track-name="think.mp3" id="play233"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url233">think</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Copied elements</h3>
<div id="list-player-songs"></div>

<hr/>
<br/><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for all ID's and use `attr(function)` which will in itself do an `each` internally

```
$newTable
    .find('[id]')
    .attr('id', function(_, id){
       return 'new-prefix' + id;
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

You could search for every element that has the `id` attr like this:

```
$newTable
    .find('[id]')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'my_'+$(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

That way, it will change the id of every element that has an id set.

Elements that don't have an ID set, wont be changed.